# Fee to publish comment paper in open access journal

Tags: publications, funding

We noticed a mistake in a previously published paper in an IEEE photonics journal. We wrote a correction and submitted it to the journal, and they accepted and published it.  Afterwords, I received an email that I have to pay $1,220, which is more than I can afford. Nor can I get funding for it, because it’s just a two page note.

My question is whether this is normal or not in IEEE paid journals.
If I have to pay the fee, is there any legal procedure to withdraw the published comment paper?

Comment: See https://www.photonicssociety.org/publications/photonics-journal/open-access to find out if you qualify for a discount on the fee.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but Still the fee is too much for me. If it was a full length paper then I will manage it from some where but the problem is that it’s just a correction in the previously published paper.

Comment: I guess your best option is to contact the editorial board of the journal and ask them about your situation.

Comment: Was there any point in the process up until now where you had to agree to the fee?  I wonder if they slipped some kind of agreement in.

Comment: I didn’t notice during submission regarding fee, however after acceptance they sent an email to pay the fee. I am worried that I can’t pay the fee and it is also hard to get discount. And also the comment paper or notes doesn’t qualify the criteria to apply for funding. Is there any legal way to retrieve this published comment paper?

Comment: You are only obliged to pay the fee if you *agreed* to it; otherwise it is not part of any contract, meaning the publisher cannot use legal means to enforce a payment. If you did not notice that you agreed to it you should be fine without paying. Unless, of course, you were negligent (e.g. you clicked on 'Agree' without having read the clearly visible terms - in which case the publisher can trust that you agreed so that the contractual obligation arises without your knowledge). Whatever the case, you should contact the editors and ask for their understanding.